# How to use session in plone sit?

Tags: python, plone

I want to create login page in plone4.3 site . when  login to my page I go to success page .if I click the back button from the browser means its go to my login page .then I click fwd button means again its redirect to success page .so I click fwd button means I want to redirect login page .how can I do this ?

Comment: you may need to use javascript for redirecting ..

Comment: you can see about python redirection here http://forum.codecall.net/topic/66988-page-redirection-in-python/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the workflow. Can you explain it deeper?

Comment: what happend if you click back after clicking on forward but before ?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to redirect back to your orginal (pre-login) page? If not, can you explain more about what you want?